# How to compute frequency with different lengths of string

Tags: r, string, frequency

I'm begining in R and it's a little bit hard for me sometimes. I have a big data frame of 100000 observations and in this data frame I have a column id and I need to compute the most frequent id in the column. But the problem is that there sometimes different id in a string separate by a '&'.
I gonna keep an exemple it's easier:

```
id             value
1                1
1                2
2&3&4            6
2&5&7&8          1
2&4&5            3
2                3
```

So, I'm supposed to obtain 2
There can be until 20 '&' in a string.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is the column `value` meant to be used ? I don't really understand it

Comment: Sorry tt can be same id separate by a '&' too!

Comment: No we just use the column id but I thought you need 2 column to form a data frame

Comment: Does something like `names(sort(table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df[,1]),'&'))),decreasing=T)[1])` suits you ? Replace `df[,1]` by `df$id` if it doesn't

Comment: It's seems to work, thanks!! But does "[1]" mean at the end of your code? Is it the first 1st string of the column when you want to classify by decreasing?

Comment: The code gets the frequency of each element via `table`. The `[1]` only selects the element with the highest frequency (because the table is sorted in decreasing order) to display. You can also remove everything before `table` and after the 3 `)` to have the frequencies for each element

Comment: I'll write an answer for future readers

Comment: Ok it's clear but my hightest frequency is "" so an empty space. I can select the second as well but do you know if I can change something to delete this empty space?

Comment: Try `names(sort(table(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df[,1]),'&')))),decreasing=T)[1])`

Answer (score 2):

The data seems to be this:

```
df<-structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "2&3&4", "2&4&5", "2&5&7&8"), class = "factor"), value = c(1L, 
2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("id", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

First step is to have a vector with all the `ids`:

```
unlist(strsplit(as.character(df[,1]),'&'))
# [1] "1" "1" "2" "3" "4" "2" "5" "7" "8" "2" "4" "5" "2"
```

then we get the frequencies:

```
table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df[,1]),'&')))

# 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 
# 2 4 1 2 2 1 1
```

and then we diplay the number with the highest frequency (the table is ordered in decreasing order):

```
names(sort(table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df[,1]),'&'))),decreasing=T)[1])
# [1] "2"
```